# How to build an multi dim. array or object with string as key?

Tags: python

I get sytax errors if I try to add a string as key with => or :

It should be like:
self.arr[0]['path'] = "*.html"

But I like to build some init variables of my class as tree like.

```
self.arr = [
            [
                "*.html",
                settings.BASE_DIR + "/html/"
            ],
            [
                "*.json",
                settings.BASE_DIR + "/jsons/"
            ]
        ]
```

Comment: Could you use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not how lists or arrays work or are meant to be working. Instead, you should consider using a `dictionary` like this:

```
self.arr = {}
self.arr["*.html"] = settings.BASE_DIR + "/html/"
self.arr["*.json"] = settings.BASE_DIR + "/jsons/"
```